# how to iterate file when if it not null

Tags: c, file, loops

For the past two days I've been stuck to make and iteration where I would create another file if it already present. when i try to iterate it always spawn either infinite loop of file/508 file is produce

```
bool y = false;
FILE *tf;
int i= 0 ;
char t[15];
do
{
    sprintf(t, "test%d.txt", i);
    tf = fopen( t, "a" ) ;
    i++;
    if (tf == NULL)
    {
        y == true;
    }
    else
    {
        fclose(tf)
    }
}
while(y != true );
```

My only solution is to make another file as a counter how many file are present

Comment: You should first reformat your code so that it is readable.

Comment: Why do you not use the assignment operator '=' instead of '==' at line y == true?

Comment: You should not compare boolean values (the result is another boolean): do  not say `while (y != true)`; say `while (!y)` instead. Although in this particular code I would write an infinite loop `for (;;)` and a `break`. Better a `break` than a control variable.

Comment: You can use [this site](http://prettyprinter.de/index.php) to format your code, though it would be better if you *write* it with the proper formatting.

Comment: Robert HARVEY thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
y == true;
```

This is a comparison whose result was dropped. It should be

```
y = true;
```

Also you should use `"r"` flag in `fopen()` when you check for file existence. `"a"` flag creates the file if it does not exist.

Comment: This is why you should compile with warnings turned on, and listen to the warnings.

Comment: Oh god, I am so ... from this problem, no one uses compiler warnings, if there were more people using them, there would be way less questions to post on SO.

Comment: my purpose is to create new file if the previous file is already filled.

Comment: Then you should not check for `tf == NULL`. You should fseek to end of file and check for file size by ftell.

Answer (score 1):

You used a comparison operator, instead of assignment operator:

```
y == true;
```

instead of

```
y = true;
```

What you've done makes only sense if you want to assert the equality of the operands, which is the return value of this expression (a boolean).

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
y = true;
```

instead of

```
y== true;
```

And also another observation is `i` is being incremented and you open new files in each iteration what if the file pointer is never NULL then you have infinite loop. Have some condition like

```
do
{

  // do stuff
}while( y!= true && i<10);
```

Something like this. This is just a presumption

Comment: truthfully i'm planning to do this it just that I want to make a progame that could create as many iteration as i wanted to and not limited even thought i could just make 1000 as restriction but still it is limited

Comment: @albertcahyawan Add an additional check if you want to restrict opening some `n` number of files as shown in the code